# How do you send additional data with a Stripe charge to be returned in a webhook?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm transitioning a website from Google Wallet for Digital Goods to Stripe and I'm trying to duplicate the old flow of

1. Customer makes purchase and `user_id`, `product_id`, `quantity`, and other arbitrary data are passed to Google Wallet
2. A postback is sent to my server including all that extra data and a secret key so I know it's not a customer spoofing a postback
3. My server assumes that means a legitimate purchase has taken place and finishes up various processing

For each purchase, my site obviously needs to know

- **What product was purchased** *(and `charge.description` can't be used as a unique identifier)*
- **Which of my site's user accounts the customer was logged in to** when the purchase was made

I'm trying to integrate Checkout and don't see

- anything in [its documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) that seems to allow arbitrary data to be passed along with a charge and
- nothing in [the API's documentation for the `charge` object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charges) (which the webhook is sending back to my server) that passes back arbitrary data.

### Use the customer object?

The customer object doesn't seem like the solution, since the API docs say "Customer objects allow you to perform recurring charges and track multiple charges that are associated with the same customer", neither of which apply to my situation.

### Handle it in the local Javascript callback?

I can do something like this,

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    token: function(token) {
        var user_id = 123;
        var product_id = 456;
        var quantity = 2;
        var arbitrary = 'data';
        // fire off a POST call to http://example.com/hey_look_a_charge with the above data
    }
});
```

But the Checkout example says that the `token` callback gets invoked "when the Checkout process is complete", not just for successful charges. The `token.id` could be stored along with the other data as a 'pending purchase' that becomes verified once the `charge.succeeded` event fires a webhook, but that might introduce a race condition, sounds convoluted as hell, and `token.id` *isn't sent back with the webhook in the first place.*

This seems like a really common requirement for payment processing, but I'm totally baffled how to practically pull it off with Stripe. Can anyone advise?

Comment: You don't need to wait for `charge.succeeded` to know that a charge succeeded, once you create the charge and get a charge object back you *know* the charge succeeded and you can at that point store these details in your database.

Comment: The documentation for Checkout doesn't mention any way to get the `charge` object back after a successful charge. It *appears* that you get the `token` object in the Javascript callback and have to wait for the `charge.succeeded` webhook to receive a `charge` object. I'm totally new to Stripe, though, and there's a good chance there's something obvious that I'm missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're confused about how Stripe Checkout works. Getting the Stripe token is only the first step in the process of handling a payment. When using Stripe [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) you get a Stripe token back that you then need to send to your server where you then use the [Create Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) API to create a charge and receive a payment.

So in your case you would be able to create the charge server-side and once the API call is made you don't need to wait for the `charge.succeeded` event in your webhook. You get either a charge object back indicating success or an error indicating the charge failed. You would then be able to update your database at that point.

Comment: But what's the use of sending token to our server to call the create charge api. I mean why can't we call the `create charge api` at my end. Can you please help me understand what the concept `Stripe` using ?

Comment: This is for Security reasons. Otherwise anyone can create a Charge client-side and charge your other cards. Also they can try to pay $0.50 for a t-shirt instead of $19.99 since it all happens client-side in JS. To avoid all those issues, Stripe requires a server to create the Charge instead

Answer (score 4):

You can add a hidden input field to the form containing the stripe script tag.

```html
<form action="/your-server-side-code" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="my_data" value="my_data_value">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_d2luBCpkXXuIVPKS7hBN43jR"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="Widget"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

then you can receive the value in the '/your-server-side-code' url.

Comment: Hidden field not getting on server side POST